# how to call multiple bash functions using | in python

Tags: python, bash, call, subprocess

I am using a scientific software (called vasp) that works only in bash, and using Python to create a script that will make multiple runs for me. When I use subprocess.check_call to call the function normally, it works fine, but when i add the '| tee tee_output' it doesn't work.

```
subprocess.check_call('vasp') #this works
subprocess.check_call('vasp | tee tee_output') #this doesn't
```

I am a noobie to python and programming altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. It executes the command (passed as a string) via a shell, instead of executing the command directly. (It's the equivalent of calling the shell itself with the `-c` flag, i.e. `Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])`):

```
subprocess.check_call('vasp | tee tee_output', shell=True)
```

But attend to the warning in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) about this method.

Comment: @user1255726: It [executes the command using a shell](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Comment: @user1255726, I'm taking you at your word that your software "only works in bash." If that's not actually true, then one of the other answers would be preferable for security reasons. Let me know if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
vasp = subprocess.Popen('vasp', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.check_call(('tee', 'tee_output'), stdin=vasp.stdout)
```

This is generally safer than using `shell=True`, especially if you can't trust the input.

Note that `check_call` will check the return code of `tee`, rather than `vasp`, to see whether it should raise a `CalledProcessError`. (The `shell=True` method will do the same, as this matches the behavior of the shell pipe.) If you want, you can check the return code of `vasp` yourself by calling `vasp.poll()`. (The other method won't let you do this.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use shell=True, it has many security holes. Instead do something like this

```
cmd1 = ['vasp']
cmd2 = ['tee', 'tee_output']

runcmd = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
runcmd2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, stdin=runcmd.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

runcmd2.communicate()
```

I know its longer, but its much safer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info in documentation:
http://docs.python.org/library/pipes.html

Just append more strings to `t` object